# How to highlight the focussed UITextField in a scroll view by moving it to the top of the key board / center of the view when it was focussed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview

in my view i have 14 text fields in a scrollview.

To move the view up /down while keyboard appears/ disappears i have set the scroll view frame sizes

```
#pragma mark - Text field view delegate methods
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; 
{
      //To move the scroll view up to avoid keybord covers the text field
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
      [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
      //scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, (scrollView.frame.origin.y - 45), scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);


      [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 1100)];

      [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;       
{   
      //To move the view down 
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
      [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
       [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 900)];
      //scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, (scrollView.frame.origin.y + 45), scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
      [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

for return key board focussed to the next field and for the last field keyboard resign

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{


      if(textField == nameField) {
            [emailText becomeFirstResponder];
      } else if(textField == emailText) {
            [mobileText becomeFirstResponder];
      }
      else if(textField == mobileText) {
            [iPhoneText becomeFirstResponder];
      }
      else if(textField == iPhoneText.value) {
            [companyText becomeFirstResponder];
      }
      else if(textField == companyText) {


       [roleText becomeFirstResponder];
  }

...
......
...........
  else if(textField == lastfield) { // Last fiels
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
  }





      return YES;
}
```

But my intension is **when ever a text field is focussed that text field is moving up to the keyboard top or center of the view**

How to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) for my apps, it seems to work perfectly for me, perhaps give it a try.